# Mouse stops working on Gnome Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: gnome, mouse, freeze

This issue has been happening to me since I switched to ubuntu.
Sometimes the mouse suddently doesnt work on Gnome GUI, if I switch to apps using `alt+tab` it works perfectly fine in all of them. The mouse moves around like it would normally do system wide, but when wanting to access for example the task bar or desktop neither of the buttons work. As mentioned, mouse works fine in all apps and the lock screen, Keyboard works all of the time

**System Information:**

- Ubuntu version 20.04.2 LTS
- OS Type: 64 bit
- Gnome Version: 3.36.8
- Windowing System: X11 
  I'm also using Tweaks with orchis theme, but I don't think that's causing an issue since it happened even without Tweaks installed.

**What apps I usually use when this happens:**
(I don't really think they matter but here they are)

- Discord
- Spotify
- Java Runtime Environment (I play Minecraft on it)
- Firefox
- Atom code editor

**What do I do to get out:**

- `ctrl + alt + REISUB`
- Pull the plug
  (Locking the screen doesn't work)

What I wanna know is why this happens and if there's any way to prevent it from happening, or if there's any way to fix it without rebooting the system.